# Is anyone working on a blockchain ethereum system for US national healthcare system insurance marketplace?

Tags: ether, bitcoin

Specifically I am asking for info on any one person or company coding to solve this huge medical insurance marketplace quagmire we are currently in. Now with Trump's latest deed our insurance premiums are going to increase dramatically. As if they were not high enough already. What I suggest is a blockchain or smart contract system whereby all insurance companies would subscribe to and adhere to pricing that is computed to give not only profitability but affordability to all. Can you imagine such a system? Many questions come to mind of course but they can all be solved through coding like everything else. Care to comment? Please add tags to help propagate this question and comments.